# Why does Listbox not filter based on mulitple dropdown fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**The Case:** 
I have a listbox that has a query as a datasource. The query contains parameters that are based on dropdown fields which are on the same userform as the listbox.

If I use only a single dropdown field as a parameter in the query, the listbox updates and shows the filtered results.

**The Issue:**
If I reference multiple dropdown fields, the query only filters based on the last dropdown that I have selected. Why is that and how can I change it to filter based on the selected values in all four dropdowns?

**The SQL:**

```
SELECT tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR AS [Retro Frei], tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status], tblISIN_Country_Table.Country
FROM (tblFUNDS INNER JOIN tblISIN_Country_Table ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblISIN_Country_Table.ISIN) INNER JOIN tblMorningstar_Data ON (tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection = tblMorningstar_Data.Fund_Selection) AND (tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblMorningstar_Data.ISIN)
GROUP BY tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status], tblISIN_Country_Table.Country, tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection
HAVING (((tblFUNDS.RDR) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnRDR].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnTax].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnDistribution].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblISIN_Country_Table.Country) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0));
```

The relevant part of my query that does the filtering is this:

```
HAVING (((tblFUNDS.RDR) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnRDR].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnTax].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnDistribution].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblISIN_Country_Table.Country) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0));
```

Comment: What event are you setting the query with?

Comment: I'm using `AfterUpdate()` and the code is just one line: `libFilterSelection.Requery`

Comment: Regarding `query only filters based on the last dropdown that I have selected`.  Can you test that a few times and make 100% certain that this is the case by changing the order in which you select dropdown options?  That particular symptom seems very odd.  Also before `libFilterSelection.Requery`  please `Debug.Print Forms("frmMain").Controls("ddnRDR").Text` and each other control in the query as well so we can see what the values are showing as, which is what the query would be using as well.

Comment: Awesome suggestions! I hadn't thought about using debug print before running the query... when I inserted the code you suggested I got an error message. So I removed the `.Text` from the end and the code worked. I saw that the values being passed were the actual values in the dropdown fields, except for the country one. That was a value (probably Access' internal reference as it is a join query). That got me thinking... I removed the `.Text` from all the query parameters except the Country one and now it works!

Comment: @Newd Opps... I was a bit too fast. It seems to filter correctly in some instances. I does however, as you suggested, depend on the order in which I click the dropdowns!

Comment: Is it possible that Access evaluates an SQL statement based on the order in which the parameters are given to it? When I set all the filters and sort "country" last, it works ok. But if I go back and then filter one of the prior criteria, I get results for many countries again.

Comment: At the times that it doesn't filter correctly. What does the `Debug.Print`'s say?

Comment: I don't know what the particular issue is, but it can be easily fixed by changing the AfterUpdate of the various comboboxes to call a new procedure "SetListboxRowSource()" which then builds the row source string explicitly with the available values already selected in the comboboxes, and sets the listbox's rowsource property to that string.